# PHP 7. Подскажите более красивый вариант перебора массива

Tags: php, массивы

Здрасьте! В общем есть массив вида `[2 => ['element_id'=> [3,2]], 1 => ['element_id'=>[1]]];`
Где ключи обозначают определенные id. Мне нужно перебрать данный массив так, чтобы внутренние элементы были сгруппированы с внешним ключом и получилась строка такого вида:

> Группа 1 (Элемент 1) AND Группа 2 (Элемент 3 + Элемент 2)

Для этих целей я написал вот такую конструкцию:

```
    $array = [2 => ['element_id'=> [3,2]], 1 => ['element_id'=>[1]]];
    ksort($array);
    $cnt = count($array);
    $i = 0;
    $string = '';
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        $i++;
        $string .= 'Группа '.$k .'';
        $i2 = 0;
        $cnt2 = count($v['element_id']);
        $string2 = '';
        foreach ($v['element_id'] as $value){
            $i2++;
            $string2 .= 'Элемент '.$value;
            if($i2<$cnt2){
                $string2 .= ' + ';
            }
        }
        $string .= ' ('. $string2.')';
        if($i<$cnt){
            $string .= ' AND ';
        }

}
echo $string; //Группа 1 (Элемент 1) AND Группа 2 (Элемент 3 + Элемент 2)
```

Вариант хоть и рабочий и выдает все что мне нужно, но у меня есть стойкое ощущение, что можно было бы сделать красивее и лучше. Вопрос к знатокам: Как сделать данное решение элегантным?

Comment: Ну такое тут больше вкусощина пойдет, вместо ' ' использовать  " " и я бы наверно всегда бы делал конкатенацию и в конце просто бы обрезал строку с AND / + , код по мне бы стал бы проще без этих ифов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = [2 => ['element_id'=> [3,2]], 1 => ['element_id'=>[1]]];
ksort($array);

$parts = [];
foreach ($array as $groupID => $elements) {
    $subParts = [];
    foreach ($elements['element_id'] as $element) {
        $subParts[] = 'Элемент ' . $element;
    }
    $parts[] = 'Группа ' . $groupID . ' (' . implode(' + ', $subParts) . ')';
}

echo implode(' AND ', $parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_map`, `array_keys`, `array_column`, `implode` вам в помощь

```
$data = [2 => ['element_id'=> [3,2]], 1 => ['element_id'=>[1]]];


$result = implode(' AND ', array_map(function($k, $v){
                            $elements = implode('+', array_map(function($e){
                                            return "Элемент $e";
                                       }, $v));
                            return "Группа $k ($elements)";
                }, 
                array_keys($data),
                array_column($data, 'element_id')
            ));
```